# Make all displays black

Tags: macos, display, automation

I use my MacBook with the internal display and two screens attached, so 3 displays in total. Sometimes I need to do work at my desk without using the computer, and I find that the displays distract me a lot. I'd like a quick way (shortcut or easily accessible script) to make all 3 displays black. One way to achieve that is to open an entirely black image in Preview and make it full screen, but I'm open to other solutions if they achieve the same goal.

How can I automate the process of opening 3 copies of an image and make them full screen, each on a different display of otherwise assign a shortcut to this?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to sleep the system?

Comment: True, that's a good starting point. I'm still interested in an answer as I sometimes also want to black out only 2 of the screens and continue using the 3rd. And sometimes I have apps running on the computer (music, or longer computations) that I'd like to stay on.

Comment: What version of **macOS** are you running and on what _model_ of **Mac**? Does your **Mac** have a **Touch Bar** or **Touch ID** sensor? Are you using an external keyboard and if yes what make and model?

Comment: MacOS 11.6. MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2020, 4 Thunderbolt 3 ports). TouchBar yes, TouchID no, but a button in the top-right corner.

Comment: Control–Shift–Power button will sleep all displays.

Comment: Very useful, didn't know! That answers the question as stated and solves one of my problems - I'd be happy to accept an answer based on this. I'd still be keen on a solution to black out only a subset of the displays. Should I ask a new question for that?

Comment: RE: " I'd still be keen on a solution to black out only a subset of the displays. Should I ask a new question for that?" --  Yes as it is extremely frowned upon to change the scope of the question in such a manner once an answer to the originally posted question is provided.

Comment: Fully understand. Answer accepted, much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can sleep all displays by pressing either of the following built-in *keyboard shortcut* as applicable:

- **Control–Shift–Power** button<sup>1</sup>
- **Control–Shift–Media Eject**

<sup>1</sup> Does not apply to the [Touch ID sensor](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT207054).